# Count punctuation in a text

Tags: php, regex

I need to count how many punctuation there is a in text. I've tried this code, but it always return 1

```
$pattern = '/^[\/,.;:\'@#~\[\]\{\}\\|<>`!"£$%^&*\(\)\-_=+]+$/';
$commas = 0;
do
{
$commas++;
}
while (preg_match($pattern,$_POST['text']) != FALSE);
echo $commas;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) along with the POSIX class [`[:punct:]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) ...

```
echo preg_match_all('/[[:punct:]]/', $_POST['text']);
```

Comment: I believe `preg_match_all` itself also returns the match count.

Comment: Yes, I switched it around. Thanks.